# Chrome sometimes ends a window and doesn't give me the option to restore that window

Tags: windows, google-chrome, tabs

I generally have 2 or 3 windows open, one for work/task related things (generally like 15 tabs), one for youtube which often grows quite large (has often grown past the 50 tabs mark), but most of them are unloaded and occasionally one with a bunch of research tabs.

Then sometimes it happens that my Chrome (Version 109, on Windows 11) just ends a window while I'm focused on another application and don't use that window. When I then notice and go to check my history, there's no "`XX closed tabs`" or something along those lines, which is rather frustrating.

I've often thought that I just noticed too late, and opened too many tabs in between, but the last couple of times, I checked my history, and the last tabs that I closed according to it where tabs from the window that's no longer there, singular ones, which I recall closing.

What could I do to prevent this? Has this happened to others, and how did you fix it? I've checked my history file too, and the window also isn't there, even when I know it should be there.

Comment: It may be an issue with your Chrome Profile

Comment: @John I have only my one single profile... Sync is on, and there's only 1 email registered for google itself as well (same google account as the profile)

Comment: If not Profile, then I do not know what else would cause this. Sorry. Perhaps try reinstalling Chrome. Uninstall, restart, install and test

Comment: You might also turn Sync off temporarily and see if Sync is causing the issue